# ASP.Net GridView - Show the last 4 digits

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my gridview, I have a column that I need everything masked but the last 4-digits. 
This is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="br_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountNumber" HeaderText="Account Number" SortExpression="AccountNumber" />
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried the Right function of SQL Server in my SQLDataSource,

```
`SELECT '****-****-****' + RIGHT (AccountNumber, 4)` FROM....
```

the issue then is, when I hit edit, and save in my GridView, it will save this in the database, for example: ****-****-****-1234

Comment: return the masked field as another column and use that column for display purpose. use the actual column for edit. this way you don't have to worry about masked values being stored in the db

Comment: You can find solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843514/show-last-4-digits-in-gridview

Comment: Curious as to the point of masking in the grid and displaying when edit is available and will display the field.  Is the edit functionality only provided to a user with privileges?  If not then doesn't this defeat the purpose of masking the account number?

Comment: The user cannot edit the account number, the admin can switch to the user profile and edit the account number.

Comment: @Mutant I tried that before I posted the question and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Return 4 digits from the database. Only update the the account number in the database if you edit the account number.

If the users need to be able to see the full account number then it defeats the purpose of masking it in the first place.

Comment: The user cannot edit the account number, the admin can switch to the user profile and edit the account number.